# Can not download VMware ESXi 4.1 Update1 from VMware site?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

I have an account and I can access the download page, but I think they have an error in the site!
instead I'm getting directed to another ISO file (VMware-Tools)
the MD5 is correct for the VMware-Tools ISO!!!

I was trying to find a way to contact them, but I can not find any place in there website !!!!

any one faced same problem?

[image]

on another place in the site, there seems to be the correct info, but it takes me to the page where the image above !!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll further down to the one labeled `ESXi 4.1 Installable Update 1 (CD ISO)` with an MD5 sum of `d68d6c2e040a87cd04cd18c04c22c998`.  It's all still there, just in an unintuitive order.

Comment: but isn't it an update CD? or is it for fresh install as well!

Comment: The CD is for fresh installs only.  You'll want the upgrade zip bundle if you're looking to update an existing host.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the same file just fine on both W7/IE9 and OSX/Safari machines, that said I think this is a question for VMWare's web support people not here.

Comment: I think it is a question for VMWare's web support people too, but how I can contact them! I can not find a page or an email to contact them!

Comment: You probably receive contact information for support after licensing thousands of dollars of software from them. :)

Comment: No, this is a website issue, they have a form to complete for issues such as this; http://www.vmware.com/contact/contactus.html?department=feedback_website&amp%3blabel=Webmaster&amp%3bref=https%253A//www.vmware.com/